# AWS CLI Errno 13 Permission Denied, cannot set credentials using aws configure command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-prompt, aws-cli, credentials

first time question so please excuse my poor question formatting. I'm running up to date(enough) Python, AWS CLI v2, installed with MSI, config and credentials file both have values, no environment variables set, Windows 10, using Command Prompt.

When I input:

```
C:\Users\correctuser> aws --version
```

This is what returns:

```
aws-cli/2.5.2 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

When I type:

```
C:\Users\correctuser> aws configure list
```

This is what I get:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                us-west-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

//I have both regular and secret access keys set in the 'credentials' file in C:\users\correctuser.aws\credentials, and the region and format set in C:\users\correctuser.aws\config.

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json

[default]
aws_access_key_id = thisisfakeaccesskeyID
aws_secret_access_key = thisisfakesecretaccesskeyID
```

And then when I type:

```
C:\Users\GitUser>aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: thisisfakeaccesskeyID
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: thisisfakesecretaccesskeyID
Default region name [us-west-2]:
Default output format [json]:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\GitUser\\.aws'
```

I heard that sometimes when your file name doesn't have a backslash at the end of it that can cause an error, though I don't think that's what it is. I've also tried running Command Prompt as administrator and that didn't help.

What do y'all think?

Comment: Is the file open in an application somewhere which is locking the file and not letting you update it? Make sure the file is closed everywhere.

Comment: Do you have a file (instead of a directory) named `.aws` in `C:\Users\GitUser` ?

Comment: File not open elsewhere,file is a file not a directory. I found the issue but haven't solved it yet. It's the read/write permissions that the user doesn't have for the file. I've tried giving access through admin and every available way i know how, but every time I hit apply and then OK, when i open it back up it has deselected the read/write option

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem you have to give write permission to the file.

**If you run on unix/OSX**

```
// Set permission
sudo chmod -R 777 /{Your_Path}/.aws/credentials 
sudo chmod -R 777 /{Your_Path}/.aws/config
```

**Windows**

1:- Right-click on the target file and select properties then select Security Tab

2:- Click Advanced and then make sure inheritance is disabled.

3:- Click apply and then click Edit in the security menu

4:- Remove all users except Admin user, which should have full control *Admin account should have all checkboxes checked on Allow column except special permission.

5:- Click Apply and then click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to give the permissions but also that did not fix the error at first.

When I checked the location the `config.ini` and `credentials.ini` did not exist.

After creating the files by editing a text file and saving it as the `.ini` files.

The error disappeared from that moment.